# How do I preserve new line characters for sendmail in bash script?

Tags: bash, echo, sendmail

Why isn't the following preserving the new line characters in the resulted email?

```
#!/bin/bash

file="/tmp/ip.txt"
address=$(curl -s http://ipecho.net/plain; echo)
ifconfig=$(ifconfig)

function build_body
{
    echo "----------------------------------------------------------------" > $file
    echo "IP Address: $address (according to http://ipecho.net/plain)" >> $file
    echo "----------------------------------------------------------------" >> $file
    echo >> $file
    echo "Result from ifconfig:" >> $file
    echo >> $file
    echo "$ifconfig" >> $file
    echo >> $file
}

build_body
msg=$(cat $file)
mail="subject:Home Server Status\nfrom:email@example.com\n$msg"
echo $mail | /usr/sbin/sendmail "email2@example.com"
```

I receive the email this script generates, however, the whole body is all on one line!
/tmp/ip.txt is exactly how I want the email to look.

Comment: Why not use the `mail` utility:  `mail -s "Subject" user@destination.example.com < /path/to/body.txt`  I usually use that.

Comment: Perfect, simple and just what I wanted...  Thanks.

Comment: Two things: You `echo $mail | /usr/sbin...`. This removes all excess white space when you do an echo without quotes. Try `echo "$mail" | /usr/bin...`. Also, there may be an issue with sendmail not sending `\r\n` at the end of each line which is what the RFC for mail requires. Try quotes around `$mail` and see if that takes care of the issue. If not, use `echo "$mail" | mail -s "$subject" $user` Note the quotes!

Answer (score 11):

I ran into this recently. I was able to resolve it adding the '-e' option to echo.

Change this:

> echo $mail | /usr/sbin/sendmail "email2@example.com"

To This:

> echo -e "$mail" | /usr/sbin/sendmail "email2@example.com"

Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 5):

You may use "here documents" (`<<END`), make the function output its results to standard output.

```
#!/bin/bash

address=$(curl -s http://ipecho.net/plain; echo)

function build_body
{
cat <<END
----------------------------------------------------------------
IP Address: $address (according to http://ipecho.net/plain) 
----------------------------------------------------------------

Result from ifconfig:

END
ifconfig
echo    
}


( cat <<END; build_body) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -i -- "email2@example.com"
Subject:Home Server Status
From:email@example.com

END
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Use double-quotes: `echo "$mail" | /usr/bin/sendmail ...`
2. Shouldn't that be two `\n` between the headers and message:

as in:

```
mail="subject:Home Server Status\nfrom:email@example.com\n\n$msg"
```

Comment: tried everything -- until I double-quoted the input. success.

Answer (score 2):

```
{
    printf "subject:Home Server Status\nfrom:email@example.com\n\n"
    cat "$file"
} | /usr/sbin/sendmail "email2@example.com"
```

With `echo $mail`, the contents of the file appear on the command line and bash processes them with word expansion.  With `cat "$file"`, the file name appears on the command line but the contents of the file do not and are thus safe from bash.